# WR not working properly on firefox?

Tags: firefox, intel-graphics

So I get this message when I start firefox :

````
[GFX1-]: More than 1 GPU from same vendor detected via PCI, cannot deduce device
[GFX1-]: Failed GL context creation for WebRender: 0
[GFX1-]: FEATURE_FAILURE_WEBRENDER_INITIALIZE_UNSPECIFIED
[GFX1-]: Failed to connect WebRenderBridgeChild.
[GFX1-]: Fallback WR to SW-WR```

I don't have any dedicated graphics card in my machine, just Intel HD Graphics.
Here's the output of ```lspci```:
```(base) antoine21839@EasyNote-TK37:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Memory Controller Hub (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 03)
00:1a.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 (rev 03)
00:1a.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 03)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 2 (rev 03)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 3 (rev 03)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 03)
00:1d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6 (rev 03)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev 93)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation ICH9M LPC Interface Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801IBM/IEM (ICH9M/ICH9M-E) 4 port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 03)
04:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8192SE Wireless LAN Controller (rev 10)
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetLink BCM57780 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe (rev 01)
````

I've seen somewhere that it might be because hardware accel isn't working, which is not the case :

```
direct rendering: Yes
```

Can someone help ? Thanks